# MAUI CarouselView: how to imitate swipe effect in code? Swipe animation does not happen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

.NET Maui CarouselView. In certain situations I want my app to take the user to the next card automatically. If I update `CarouselView.Position` or `CarouselView.CurrentItem` in code behind, it "jumps" to the next card immediately, no animation. Is it possible to imitate user's swipe? Or as a workaround, maybe somehow apply non-native-CarouselView animation manually to the CarouselView. Please advise.

Comment: There's a [ScrollTo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/scrolling#scroll-an-item-at-an-index-into-view) that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: it works indeed! Add it as an answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CarouselView contains a ScrollTo method that will animate the scroll for you. You either scroll to an index or a specific item.

Give your CarouselView a name in the XAML, and then in the code behind call the ScrollTo.

To scroll to an index:

```
carouselView.ScrollTo(6);
```

To scroll to a specific item:

```
var viewModel = BindingContext as MyViewModel;
var item = viewModel.Items.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "TheBest");
carouselView.ScrollTo(item);
```

These methods have to be called from the code behind, so if you're using a MVVM approach, you'll need to fire an event or command from your VM for your code behind to act on.

For additional info, take a look at the [ScrollTo method docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/scrolling#scroll-an-item-at-an-index-into-view) from Microsoft.